What is the dual space of $c_{00}$?
Consider $c_{00}$ (Space of sequences that has finite nonzero elements) equipped with norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$. Its algebraic dual space $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ is mentioned in this answer. However it can't be dual space as functional $f\in \mathbb{C}^\infty$ can be unbounded.
I only know $(c_{00})^* \supset \ell^1$ because $(c_0)^* = \ell^1$. I don't know $(c_{00})^* = \ell^1$ or the dual space would be larger.

Its closure is $c_0$ so its dual is same as that of $c_0$, namely $\ell^{1}$.

Does it mean the space and the closure of this space must have the same dual space? Looks like it comes from the continuity of functional.

Any continuous linear functional on a subspace has a  unique norm preserving extension to the closure of the subspace, so the duals are the same.

Where does the "unique" come from? By Hahn-Banach theorem we can only get the existence. Thank you for your help.

Hahn-Banach Theorem is not required. Uniqueness is just a basic Topology argument.
